# How do I open a UIImagePickerController from a presented view controller?

Tags: ios

**Update at bottom of question**

Here's what I'm looking to do:

Main ViewController opens a new ViewController (i don't want a navigation bar, so do I have to do this modaly?) which then opens the camera.

In the main view controller I have this being called on a button press:

```
CameraProcessViewController *controller = [[CameraProcessViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraProcessViewController" bundle:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

Which opens up the next controller.  In that next controller in the viewDidLoad method I have:

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [imagePicker setDelegate: self];
    [imagePicker setAllowsEditing:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"Has camera");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Has no camera");
}
```

I've tried both presentModalViewController and presentViewController and every combination of the two between the main view controller and this child one, however the camera never opens.  When I move the camera code into the main view controller it opens fine.

I've looked and looked and I can't find anything saying why this would be.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I found that in the viewDidLoad method I can call this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(openCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

And it loads it up just fine.  Is this okay or is this not recommended?  Seems a tad hacky!

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is not the right place to do this. You could try `viewWillAppear` but that might be too early, too. Otherwise, `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Actually I just found that if I move the camera code to its own method and then call it in viewDidLoad with this:

    [self performSelector:@selector(openCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

Then it works!  Is there a better method?  Somebody else suggested in awakenFromNib but that didn't work.

Comment: I almost suggested that. It's later than `viewDidLoad` but earlier than `viewWillAppear`. But `viewDidLoad` is semantically wrong: you can cause the view to load without it ever appearing on screen and it doesn't make sense to show the camera if you never show the other controller. You, of course, may not be using it this way. `viewWillAppear` is more correct: you know it's going to appear. Fair warning that presenting one controller on top of another immediately tends to be fragile, i.e., have problems with OS upgrades. The less aggressive you are about timing, the more stable it is.